# TexStudio adding custom include command

Tags: texstudio, include

When TexStudio sees `\include` command in the source file it will add the included file to the document structure pane.
I am using `leadsheet` package which defines `\includeleadsheet` command.
Is it possible to setup TexStudio so the `\includeleadsheet` is also recognized as `\include`
and all files included with it are also added to the structure pane.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/feature-requests/1075/, you can add a custom .cwl file.

Create a file, eg. `a.cwl`, with the following content

```
\includeleadsheet{file}#i
```

If you use Windows, put the file in `%appdata%\texstudio\completion\user`.

Then restart texstudio, in Options -> Completion, permanently enable `a.cwl`.

For more details, check https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/master/utilities/manual/usermanual_en.html

Comment: This should be unnecessary because texstudio now has a built-in cwl for `leadsheets` that adds the OP's desired functionality